# error because of changing the package name

Tags: java, android

hi i created all my apps in a single package name, when i was to upload it, i was success in uploading my first app. when i was to upload my second app i came to know that 2 app with same package name cannot be uploaded. Its not possible for me to create the second app once again with a new package name so because of my urgent i searched for a solution in net and i found that by refactor (i am using eclipse) i can change the package name and i did the same. But the name is not changed in the manifest file and i changed manually. Then i found some errors in all of my java class file showing error in the line "import.(package name).R", so i deleted all those lines. Now there is no error but the new problem is the app is running partially. The parsing activities which have been designed in my app are not running. Main part of my app is that only. Is there any solution to overcome this, as i am a new developer pls help me........

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have your activities declared as:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.Name"/>
```

or

```
<activity android:name=".Name"/>
```

If that's the case, you must change them to:

```
<activity android:name="old.package.where.they.are.Name"/>
```

That's because your activities are in the same package where they have been, and the only thing you changed was the name of the application package. So now you need to refer to the activities by their full path.

Your new package can be called as you want, and the only thing you have to change in code are the references to the `old.package.R` class (I think you already did so).

Answer (score 0):

Do a search and replace of old package for new package and also make sure to remove bin folder before re-building your project.

Answer (score 0):

You could've just changed the package name in the manifest, then provide a fully qualified name for your activities and receivers in the manifest.

But since you've started moving the whole app to a different package name, go on. This is something that should've been done from the very beginning.